# MS access Certain Column into Rows

Tags: ms-access

I have below Source Columns, I like to convert into target format shown in MS Access, how do I do that ?

Source Data

```
Role    OrgName Market1 Value1  Market2 Value2  Market3 Value4  Market5 Value5
R1      O1      M1      V1      M2      V2      M3      V3      M4      V4
```

Target data After Converted.

```
Role OrgName Market Value 
R1      O1      M1  V1
R1      O1      M2  V2
R1      O1      M3  V3
R1      O1      M4  V4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a UNION query. There is no wizard or designer for UNION, must type or copy/paste in SQLView of query builder. Limit of 50 SELECT lines. UNION will not allow duplicate rows, use UNION ALL if you want to allow duplicate rows.

```
SELECT Role, OrgName, Market1 AS Market, Value1 AS Data FROM table
UNION SELECT Role, OrgName, Market2, Value2 FROM table
UNION SELECT Role, OrgName, Market3, Value3 FROM table
UNION SELECT Role, OrgName, Market4, Value4 FROM table;
```